# Edit controls for specific role in the dockbar

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, roles

I have this requirement:
I want to show "edit controls" in the dockbar only for users of specific role, but I don't find anything, I don't need "edit", "preview" and "add", only the edit controls, I try with permission for role but add these 4 elements.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Did you try making these changes in theme for dockbar template file,using specific role conditions for users?

Comment: Giving specific detailed information on what has been already tried gives more ideas to others on possible resolutions. Thanks.